# Change accept button with tabs

Tags: c#, button, tabs

I have a windows form application written in C# and it has three tabs and I would like the accept button change with the active tab.  Like When I am in tab 1 I want button _1 to be the accept button but when I am in tab 3 I want button_3 to be my accept button.  I cannot figure out how to do this and maybe I'm not using the correct terms in my searches but I cannot find any good resources online showing me how to do this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Best guess would be to hook in to the [`SelectedIndexChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tabcontrol.selectedindexchanged.aspx) event on the tab control and change the [`AcceptButton`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.acceptbutton.aspx) depending on which tab is selected. Pseudo-code:

```
Form_OnLoad(...)
{
    this.tabControl.SelectedIndexChanged += (s,e) => {
        TabControl tab = s as TabControl;
        switch (tab.SelectedIndex){
            case 3:
                this.AcceptButton = this.button_3;
                break;
            case 2:
                this.AcceptButton = this.button_2;
                break;
            case 1:
            default:
                this.AcceptButton = this.button_1;
                break;
        }
    };
}
```

Or something of the sort.

Comment: Neat idea +1. This could let you change the text of the `AcceptButton`, but I really don't think this is practical for changing the function.  (Also, I think that you meant to hook into the `SelectedIndexChanged` event, `Selected` fires every time the control is clicked).

Comment: I was under the impression they wanted to change the button binding and not just the text. And you are probably correct, you want to bind to when the index changes not when a tab iis simply clicked

Answer (score 2):

You can do different things based on the tab that is currently selected by using the following code in the `AcceptButton_Click` event handler:

```
if (tabControl1.SelectedTab == tabPage1)
{
    //Do something
}
else if (tabControl1.SelectedTab == tabPage2)
{
    //Do something different
}
```

If you prefer to work with strings, each tab page has a unique name:

```
switch (tabControl1.SelectedTab.Name)
{
    case "Tab1Name":
        //Do something
        break;
    case "Tab2Name":
        //Do something different
        break;
}
```

If this answered your question, please [mark it as the answer to your question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235).

Answer (score 2):

TabControl have SelectedIndexChanged event.

```
private void tabControl1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (tabControl1.SelectedTab == tabControl1.TabPages["RenewalTab"])
        {
            this.AcceptButton = btnRenewal;
        }
        else if (tabControl1.SelectedTab == tabControl1.TabPages["SellerTab"])
        {
            this.AcceptButton = btnSeller;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Some explanations would significantly improve the quality of your answer