# AcceptButton for Different Tabs

Tags: c#, forms, visual-studio

I'm new to Visual Studio and am converting a C# console app to VS so that I can give it a GUI.  The GUI piece is definitely a learning curve.

I have a main Form1 with Tab1 and Tab2.  I can call this.AcceptButton, but it only appears to be at the form level.  Is there a way for each tab to have an AcceptButton?  I can't call this.Tab1.AcceptButton, however when I am in Tab2, the function of AcceptButton doesn't seem to trigger.  Is it because the button doesn't exist on the tab that is in focus?

I could certainly forgo using AcceptButton if there's not a clean way to do this, but it would increase the usability of the application.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: you need to clarify what `AcceptButton` does. Is its action dependent on tab selected or not. BTW you can add separate buttons to each tab and assign each one respective handler to perform tab specific task.

Comment: AcceptButton is a property of Form that allows <Enter> to default to that button's action.

See:  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.acceptbutton%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

I don't think <Enter> can target based on a handler - or at least not beyond the handler provided by AcceptButton.  Though if there's a way, I'd love to hear about it.  I just haven't been able to find anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can listen to `SelectedIndexChanged` event on your `TabControl`. So whenever tab is change this event will fire and you can use assign another button to `AcceptButton`.

Have a look at this: [Change accept button with tabs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14045887/2931427)