# Different AcceptButton for different Panels on Form

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have a form with a <kbd>Search</kbd> button & <kbd>Submit</kbd> button, they are sitting on different panels but in the same form. I want to use the `AcceptButton` property of the `Form` with both buttons based on criteria.

The user will search for a ticket using the box on the right panel, which will populate the datagridview below. The user will then select a row, which I have bound to the text boxes on the left panel. The New Asset textbox is blank, so the user will have to populate that before hitting submit.

Is there anyway to bind the `AcceptButton` Property to the search textbox (right panel) if the new asset number textbox is null and then bind the property to the submit button (left panel) after the user populates the text box.

Sorry if this is hard to understand. I am still learning c# and all of the things I can do with it.

[image: snip it of app so you can get a better idea]

Comment: You're not describing what you want precisely enough to identify a reasonable answer.  What is an "accept button property?"

Comment: If you're trying to make one button do two different things, that's probably not a good idea.

Comment: Acceptbutton is a property of the form that binds a button to the enter key?

Comment: This is my understanding of the question: There are two sets of controls on the form. Each set has its own default button and OP is looking for a way to trigger the default button regarding to the active set of controls. `Submit` for left panel (when any of left side controls has focus), `Search` for right panel (when search box has focus).

Comment: I'm not sure why people are having a hard time understanding what is required here. The answer would be to handle the TextChanged event of the New Asset TextBox, when you can parse the text as a number then set the Forms accept button to the Submit button and when you can't then set the accept button to the search button. I would also suggest using a NumericUpDown instead of a textbox so you don't have to worry about non-numeric entries in that field.

Comment: It's probably be less confusing to present the detailed input as a separate (modal?) form rather than changing what keys do - what if they decide to "back out" but have already filled in the info? They go to do another search, completely change the search text, hit enter and submit instead!

Comment: If you want to use the `enter` key depending on the content of controls, and other rules, than better dont set the `AcceptButton` of any button. Use `keydown`events to catch the `enter` and then perform logic to determine what to do. This will also keep your code better organized

Comment: But I would take @Damien_The_Unbeliever advise, don't make it confusing for your users, don't allow any room for mistakes

Comment: While I also believe the UI design can be improved, but in general having multiple default button for different parts of a page can be considered as a normal requirement, like html form elements which are supposed to run their submit button code if you press enter on any form element, while you can have multiple form on a single page.

Comment: @RezaAghaei Fair enough. But still using the `AcceptButton` is not a good idea for a `WinForms` project in this case. Better to catch the `enter` like in your answer. Then you can run additional checks before clicking the button

Comment: Check this QA:  https://stackoverflow.com/q/14045825/885920

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **Note:** While I also believe the UI design in the question case can be improved, but in general having multiple default button for different parts of a page can be considered as a normal requirement, like html `form` elements which
>   are supposed to run their submit button code if you press enter on any
>   form element, while you can have multiple form on a single
>   page.

What you need to do is overriding `ProcessDialogKey` and check if the first panel contains focus then perform click of the first button and if the second panel contains focus then perform click of the second button:

```
protected override bool ProcessDialogKey(Keys keyData)
{
    if (keyData == Keys.Enter)
    {
        if (panel1.ContainsFocus)
        {
            button1.PerformClick();
            return true;
        }
        if (panel2.ContainsFocus)
        {
            button2.PerformClick();
            return true;
        }
    }
    return base.ProcessDialogKey(keyData);
}
```

You also have the option of handling `Enter` event of controls and assign `AcceptButton` of the form based on the focused control. But above/below
 solutions are more general with less code.

**Note - Creating a Panel class having AcceptButton property**

Apart from above solution, as a more reusable solution for those who wants to handle such cases by less code, you can use such panel class having `AcceptButton` property:

```
using System.Windows.Forms;
public class MyPanel : Panel
{
    public Button AcceptButton { get; set; }
    protected override bool ProcessDialogKey(Keys keyData)
    {
        if (keyData == Keys.Enter)
        {
            AcceptButton?.PerformClick();
            return true;
        }
        return base.ProcessDialogKey(keyData);
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to check whether the New Asset textbox is populated in order to decide which button to click according to the question.

Comment: @HandbagCrab While the code can be easily added the the `ProcessDialogKey` method, but I personally prefer to keeps clean and separate the concerns, so I''' put all validations in `Validating` events, for example handle `textBox1.Validating` event and set `e.Cancel = string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox1.Text);`. You can mix it with `ErrorProvider` as well.

Comment: Let's keep the answer more general and more useful for future readers.

Comment: Works great @RezaAghaei - Appreciate it!